# Android - EditText border is not visible

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Hi have a issue with the border from EditText

Here is my background/border xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
    <solid  android:color="#efefef"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#efefef"/>
</shape>
```

But the border is not showing.

**Edit:**

Here my EditText Code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/stackoverflow"
    android:layout_width="201dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="stackoverflow"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/stackoverflow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stackoverflow"
    tools:targetApi="o" />
```

Comment: Your solid and stroke color is same.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same issue if I changed the color of stroke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code works, but the problem is you use the same color for border and solid.
so the border will be as a part of solid.
try to change the color of the border like this.

```
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#3a3a3a"/>
```

Based on your update, you have some errors in your EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/stackoverflow"
    android:layout_width="201dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="stackoverflow"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/stackoverflow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stackoverflow"
    tools:targetApi="o" />
```

1- there is no `stackoverflow` inputType

2- when using `android:backgroundTint`, the view will take its color, so background will be useless.

try to remove `android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"`
and a`ndroid:inputType="stackoverflow"`.

don't forget to change `stroke` color

Comment: Thanks, but still the same issue

Comment: Yes, sure! Thanks for your help @Momen Zaqout
It's too long, I have edited my Post at the top.

Comment: see the new comment

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from the code bud-

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

And also use different color for stroke and solid in the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the color of stroke and try increasing the stroke width

Comment: Thanks but issue still exists.